# How do you properly expose global functions?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a global function that is accessible within all of my jasmine spec files (without having to import / require anything).

I've tried doing this in my test entrypoint file:

```
(window as any).doIt = function(arg: any) {
  console.log('doin it!', arg);
};
const context = require.context('../../../app/javascript/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
```

However, when I make a `.spec.ts` file do:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  doIt('doin it');
});
```

I get: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'doIt'.`

How do I make this function available in my spec files?

Comment: are you using webpack? what transpiler are you using?

Comment: yes, webpack 5, and babel with ts-loader

Comment: `interface Window { doIt: (x: any) => void; } window.doIt = function(x) {...};`

Comment: I haven't tried with jasmine but, you can use [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) instead of `window`. It works for me with jest.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I had tried that previously.. I still get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'doIt'.`

Comment: @UgurEren I tried that, and I got `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'global'.`

Comment: Is this error just showing up in your IDE or does it show up when you run tests? If the former, you've probably excluded the test files from your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, when I run tests.

Comment: Please check my answer this is something I do a lot in different apps

Answer (score -1):

The way I do this using webpack is like this:

I create a webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode:'production',
  entry: './TypeScript/AppEntry/Program.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts','.js'],
  },
  output: {    
    library: {
      name: 'App',
      type: 'assign-properties'
    }
  },
};
```

So **"TypeScript/AppEntry/Program.ts"** is a file that acts as the **"Entry Point"** of the typescript app.

The **"output"** part tells webpack the root "namespace(**library/name**)" which in this case is **"App"** and the "strategy(**library/type**)" which is **"assign-properties"**.

Now inside my **"Program.ts"** file I have:

```
import { Operations } from "./Operations";//here I import my public facade
//import { OtherOperations } from "./OtherOperations"; this could be another facade

//This is the entry point of the application
//Here we load all the "public" facades
//These facades are available from the html. Meaning globally


export {
    //Operations
    Operations,
    //you could export more facades
    //like this:
    //OtherOperations
};
```

So this basically exports each **"file"** I want to make **"public or global"**.

In my **"Operations.ts"** I can put any functions I want to make global like this:

```
export class Operations {
      static HelloFromGlobalFunction = () => {
        console.log("Hello World);
    };
}
```

To call this function I could even do it from HTML like this:

```
onclick="App.Operations.HelloFromGlobalFunction();"
```

Also you can have many different **"public global facades"** by creating other **"Operation"** files and exporting them in the **"Program.ts"** file.

Also notice this is one way of doing this but webpack supports a number of different **"library types"** in the **"output"** section.

Please refer to the [Output Library Type](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytype) documentation in the webpack website.

Comment: I am trying to do this in my test environment..  Angular autogenerated a karma config, which does not have a webpack config, and when I try to add one, I get errors...  see: https://github.com/ryanclark/karma-webpack/issues/519